# What is the best way to run a PHP script multiple times asynchronously in windows?

Tags: php, asynchronous, multiple-instances

Setup: Windows XP, XAMP with PHP 5

Hello!
I have searched stackoverflow, and googled around, but i can't seem to find what i'm looking for (think). Someone has mention using windows scheduler, but i don't think that is appropriate for this use. CGI Cron job has also been mentioned.

Is it possible to create a batch script that runs this multiple times:

```
"C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
```

Will it be asynchronous?

What i want to do:
I have created a user class that runs random requests. I'm storing statistics of time and usage from that object to a database when it is finished running.

I want to run this script asynchronous (Maybe 100 or more instances of it) so that i can simulate a great usage of the requests.

Any idea of how i can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you attempting to simulate load? If so, use one of the dedicated testing tools.

Comment: Does XAMPP include [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to start as many instances as you like. They should be started as different threads if you do not insist of waiting for a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
spawn "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"
```

... and so forth?

Answer (score 0):

Well this will depend on your machine , but basically you could create a bat script...
simple loop for 1 to 100

```
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,100) DO (
  "C:\Program Files\Xampp\PHP\PHP.exe" -f "c:\htdocs\my_script_to_run.php"

)
```

and then get it to sleep inside the loop.
There are versions that don't have the sleep command as I've seen in this link
http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html

try it out... with the ping trick you might even get some entropy in the times..

Comment: i'll give it a shot if i don't find any dedicated testing tools to use for this.

Comment: apache has a stress testing tool, it'scalled JMETER it might be of interest to you in this case.